# Problem in understanding commutation relation in the article "Change of variables and equivalence theorems in quantum field theories"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, commutator

Let ${\phi}_{\boldsymbol{r}}(r=1,2, \ldots, n)$ be a set of $\mathrm{n}$ boson fields with Lagrangian density
$$
\mathscr{L}=\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2} \dot{\phi}_{r}^{2}+G\left(\phi_{r}\right)
$$
and let $\phi_{s}^{\prime}=\phi^{\prime}{ }_{s}\left(\phi_{r}\right)$ be a redefinition of the field $\phi_r$

Suppose we have $\left[\dot{\phi}_{r}, \phi_{s}\right]=\Delta \delta_{r s}$

Now in this article  [Change of variables and equivalence theorems in quantum field theories](https://inspirehep.net/literature/40210) they have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left[\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \phi^{\prime}_s}, \phi^{\prime}_{r}\right] &=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{a}\left\{\left[\dot{\phi}_{a}, \phi_{r}^{\prime}\right] \frac{\partial \phi_{a}}{\partial \phi^{\prime}{ }_{s}}+\frac{\partial \phi_{a}}{\partial \phi_{s}^{\prime}}\left[\dot{\phi}_{a}, \phi^{\prime}_r\right]\right\} \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{a}\left\{\Delta \frac{\partial \phi_{r}^{\prime}}{\partial \phi_{a}} \frac{\partial \phi_{a}}{\partial \phi_{s}^{\prime}}+\Delta \frac{\partial \phi_{a}}{\partial \phi_{s}^{\prime}} \frac{\partial \phi_{r}^{\prime}}{\partial \phi_{a}}\right\}=\Delta \frac{\partial \phi_{r}^{\prime}}{\partial \phi^{\prime}}=\Delta \delta_{r s} .
\end{aligned} \tag 1
$$

Why we have
$\left[\dot{\phi}_{a}, \phi_{r}^{\prime}\right]=\Delta \frac{\partial\phi_{r}^{\prime}}{\partial \phi_a}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property of commutators:

$$[A,[A,B]]=0~~\Rightarrow~~[F(A),B]=[A,B]\frac{\partial F}{\partial A}.$$

So, assuming $[\phi_s,\Delta]=0$, you have

$$[\dot{\phi}_a,\phi_r'(\phi)]=-[\phi_r'(\phi),\dot{\phi}_a]=-[\phi_s,\dot{\phi_a}]\frac{\partial\phi'_r}{\partial\phi_s}=\Delta\delta_{as}\frac{\partial\phi'_r}{\partial\phi_s}=\Delta\frac{\partial\phi'_r}{\partial\phi_a}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that $\phi'_{r}$ is an analytic function. Then, we can expand $\phi'_{r}(\phi_{s})$ as
$$
\phi'_{r}(\phi_{s}) = \sum_{s,n} c_{s,n} \phi_{s}^{~n},
$$
where $\{c_{s,n}\}$ is a set of c-numbers, whose elements are expansion coefficients. Since $[\dot{\phi}_{r},\phi_{s}^{~n}] = \Delta \delta_{rs}n\phi_{s}^{~n-1}$, we can conclude
$$
[\dot{\phi}_{a},\phi_{r}'] = \sum_{n} c_{a,n} [\dot{\phi}_{a},\phi_{a}^{~n}] = \Delta\sum_{n} nc_{a,n} \phi_{s}^{~n-1} = \Delta \frac{\partial \phi_{r}'}{\partial \phi_{a}}.
$$